# Rewrite Log2 racket function into OCaml function?

Tags: scheme, ocaml, racket

```
(define log2 
        (lambda (n) (if (= n 1) 0 (+ 1 (log2 (quotient (+ n 1) 2))))))
```

I am trying to learn how to create a function in OCaml, so far I have came up with this.

```
let rem x y =                    (* I found this helper function from google*)
        let rec aux acc i n =
        if i=n then acc else
        if acc+1=y then aux 0 (i+1) n else
        aux (acc+1) (i+1) n in
        aux 0 0 x;;

let rec log2 x = 
        match x with
        | 1 -> 0
        | 1 + log2 (rem x+1 2);;
```

I cannot figure out the last expression that I am using. I want to know a way of adding 1 and call log2 function "**1** + log2 (rem x+1 2);;"

Answer (score 1):

A couple of comments:

If you just want to know whether `x` = 1, an `if` statement is probably clearer than a match.

It seems to me that the scheme function `quotient` corresponds (at least in this case) to the OCaml `/` operator. I don't see a need for `rem`.

The last case of your `match` (if you want to use a match) would look something like this:

```
| _ -> 1 + log2 (rem (x + 1) 2)
```

(However, I don't think you need to use `rem` or a match.)

Answer (score 1):

AFAICT this `rem` is the same as built-in [`mod` operator](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/expr.html#ss%3Aexpr-operators).

`rem a b` and `a mod b` seem to give the same results (except `rem -4 6` seems to go into an infinite loop but `mod` works fine)

However if we substitute `mod` for `rem` and implement the fixes from other answers we find our `log2` function still gives wrong answers.

It seems that Racket [`quotient` function](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._quotient%29%29) is not the same as `rem`/`mod` ... it seems to be doing 'floor division'. As noted in Jeffrey Scofield's answer, we can do floor division in OCaml using the integer division operator `/`.

So a working version of the `log2` function looks like:

```ml
let rec log2 x =
  match x with
  | 1 -> 0
  | _ -> 1 + log2 ((x + 1) / 2)
```

Also note there is a [`Float.log2` function](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Float.html#VALlog2) in the stdlib, so an alternative definition for integers would be:

```ml
let log2 x = (Float.of_int x) |> Float.log2 |> Float.ceil |> Int.of_float
```

For fun I did a quick [benchmark](https://chris00.github.io/ocaml-benchmark/doc/benchmark/Benchmark/index.html)...

```
utop # let results = Benchmark.throughputN ~repeat:3 1 [
  ("log2 rec", log2, 152347);
  ("log2 stdlib", log2_stdlib, 152347);
];;

utop # Benchmark.tabulate results;;
                   Rate             log2 rec log2 stdlib
   log2 rec   4415838+-   2836/s          --        -97%
log2 stdlib 142215300+-1643005/s       3121%          --
```

..so the stdlib version is approx 30x faster :)

(that was calculating log2 of `152347` ... there was less difference with smaller numbers and more with bigger numbers)

Answer (score 0):

```
 | x -> 1 + log2 (rem x+1 2);;
```

Comment: You need to parenthesize `x + 1`.

Comment: You are right I need to use quotient not remainder.